# No me llega los valores desde AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, spring

Estoy tratando de enviar unos valores desde *AJAX* a mi controlador pero no me llegan. He mirado algunas páginas web pero no encontrado la solución a este problema.

En el código *jQuery*:

```
function add_tipoDoc() {
  var idTi = document.getElementById("tipoDocumental.idTipoDocumental").value;
  var capa = document.getElementById("divlistar");
  $.ajax({

    type: "get",
    dataType: 'text',
    url: "select_tipodoc.htm",
    data: {
      'valorP': idTi
    },
    success: function(response) {
      var z = JSON.parse(response);
      $("#tableindice").find("tr").remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        var htfil = "<hr/><tr>";
        var htcol1 = "<td>" + "<label name='nombres' for='normal' class='control-label'>" + z[i] + "</label></td>";
        var htcol2 = "<td>" + "<input name='valores' type='text' cssClass='form-control' placeholder='Ingrese Valor'/></td>";
        var htfil2 = "</tr>";
        var htfin = htfil + htcol1 + htcol2 + htfil2;
        $('#tableindice').append(htfin);
      }
  },
  //...
```

En el HTML:

```
<div id="divlistar">
  <table id="tableindice">
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Si tienes las herramientas de desarrollador en tu navegador, debería haber una ventana de Red/Network mostrando las comunicaciones. Allí debería aparecer si tu página se intenta conectar al servidor, qué devuelve el servidor, etc...

Comment: Para ver que está fallando es necesario también el código del controlador.

Comment: a ok gracias lo voy probar

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es la `url` del `ajax` , creo que esta mal escrito tu url no es un `html`

```
function add_tipoDoc() {
  var idTi = document.getElementById("tipoDocumental.idTipoDocumental").value;
  var capa = document.getElementById("divlistar");
  $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        dataType: 'text',
        url: "select_tipodoc.html",
        data: {
          'valorP': idTi
        },
        success: function(response) {
          var z = JSON.parse(response);
          $("#tableindice").find("tr").remove();
          for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
            var htfil = "<hr/><tr>";
            var htcol1 = "<td>" + "<label name='nombres' for='normal' class='control-label'>" + z[i] + "</label></td>";
            var htcol2 = "<td>" + "<input name='valores' type='text' cssClass='form-control' placeholder='Ingrese Valor'/></td>";
            var htfil2 = "</tr>";
            var htfin = htfil + htcol1 + htcol2 + htfil2;
            $('#tableindice').append(htfin);
          }

        },
```

Comment: `.htm` y `.html` son formatos practicamente iguales, se usa .htm para mantener compatibilidad con SO muy antiguos, lo que si me cuadraría es que hacer una petición `ajax` a un `.html` o `.htm` no tiene sentido, no hay ningún controlador dentro de un `.html`

Comment: ¿Por qué asumes que `su controlador debe estar en un php`? Hay más plataformas web que PHP, y la pregunta tiene especificado el tag `spring`. Dicho esto, estoy de acuerdo en que una URL que acabe en `.htm` (o `.html`) parece hacer referencia a una página HTML estática y no aun controlador que general JSON de forma dinámica....

Comment: Mejor que ponga el codigo de su contralador y listo :D

Comment: @SJuan76 ¿Porque asumes que yo estaba diciendo que su controlador fuera en PHP?¿Ves la PHP escrito en mi comentario? ¿Cual es tu aportación, si simplemente has hecho que pareciera que hablara sin saber para después poner lo mismo que he dicho yo? xD

Comment: @SJuan76 En ese caso me disculpo, pero he vuelto de comer y justo he visto ese mensaje debajo del mio  y no entendía muy bien que sentido podía tener...

Comment: Creo que ademas de todo lo que ya comentaron creo que igual tendríamos que tomar en cuenta que en Ajax esta diciendo en el datatype:'text' y en el response espera un JSON, creo yo que debería de tener un datatype JSON si es lo que espera como respuesta, y sin duda tendriamos que esperar a ver su controlador.

Comment: En las etiquetas de la pregunta, especifica `Spring`, por lo que supongo que su backend esté desarrollado utilizando este framework.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, creo que primero que nada sería bueno que compartieras parte de tu back-end para poder entender mejor lo que podría estar mal. Saludos.

Comment: Hola Jarboox, este tipo de comentarios no son adecuados para formar una respuesta, para sugerencias, petición de más información, etc. existen los comentarios de la pregunta, igual que hizo SJuan76. [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) tienes más información.